# Proving continuity of a partial derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $f(x,y) = xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$

and let $f(x,y) = 0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Prove that the partial derivative of f with respect to x is continuous at $(0,0)$.

I found the partial derivative to be equal to:

$y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)$    /   $(x^2+y^2)^2$

Now I know I need to take the limit as x goes to 0.

$\lim_{x\to0}$  $y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)$    /   $(x^2+y^2)^2$

It follows that this is equal to $-y$ which is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for all y .

Thus our partial derivative is continuous at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to check that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{ (x^2+y^2)^2}=0$$

which is true indeed

$$\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{ (x^2+y^2)^2} =r\cdot f(\theta) \to 0$$

Comment: Why are we taking the limit as y goes to 0? I thought that we only took x to 0?

Comment: we need to check that $f_x(x,y)$ is continuous as a function of $x$ and  $y$.